# apt-get update 404 error for groovy

Tags: 14.04, apt

I got a warning

```
W Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/groovy-dev/groovy/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

What is wrong with my `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse main restricted universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse main restricted universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

# VirtualBox VBOX
# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no problem  with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` using

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

search `PPA` file that is related to `groovy-dev` and detete that then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

404 error comes when that web page not available there.

Comment: I can't find any file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. So, there is no `PPA` file related to groovy-dev. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

there is in fact no release for trusty:

if you go to

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/groovy-dev/groovy/ubuntu/dists/
```

you will see that `trusty` is missing.

Comment: Yes, I see. Maybe it was there, then was removed?

I got 

> groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.7.0_79 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux